# Запрос на обновление в анонимном блоке дает ошибку, но работает вне его?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Пробую добавить столбец таким скриптом:

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE ADD new_id number;

DECLARE
    MAX_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN   
    SELECT max(id) INTO MAX_ID FROM some_table;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE sequence temp_seq start WITH '||MAX_ID||' increment by 1';
    UPDATE MY_TABLE SET new_id = temp_seq.nextval;
END;
/
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Error report -
> ORA-06550: line 6, column 34:
> PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

Но если выполнить обновление после PL/SQL блока, то оно работает:

```
DECLARE
    MAX_ID NUMBER;
BEGIN   
    SELECT max(id) INTO MAX_ID FROM some_table;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE sequence temp_seq start WITH '||MAX_ID||' increment by 1';
END;
/
UPDATE MY_TABLE SET new_id = temp_seq.nextval;
```

Почему обновление внутри блока дает ошибку?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Update within anonymous block fails but works out of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62322850) от участника [Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/909414/rohit)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62322850

Answer (score 2):

Перед выполнением PL/SQL блок компилируется и все идентификаторы в статических запросах должны быть известны. Последовательность `temp_seq` в этот момент не существует.

Сделать надо так:

```
create table tab (id int, memo varchar2 (96))
/
alter table tab add new_id number
/
col maxid new_value maxid noprint 
select 999 maxid from dual
/
create sequence temp_seq start with &maxid nocache
/
begin 
    update tab set new_id = temp_seq.nextval; 
end;
/
```

> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.